# how to read a child by add click event on parent?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, event-capturing

I am printing the table dynamically and I added a click event on the whole parent. But the click event is invoking without any click.and when I print by the table and when I press the child button the event listener is not responding?

```js
document.querySelector("#mL").addEventListener('click',EandD);
         var EandD = function(event){
            var itemid =  event.target.parentNode.id;
            console.log(itemid);
            
            }
```

```html
<!--the table prints dynamically from firebase server-->
<tbody class='movie-list' id="mL">

        {  <!--  <tr>
     <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning d-inline-block"><ion-icon class="del" name="create-outline"></ion-icon></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-success d-none"><ion-icon class="del"name="checkmark-circle-outline"></ion-icon></button> </td>
      <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><ion-icon class="del"name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon></button></td>
    </tr> -->}
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the table in a clickable element like `<button>` or `<a>` and then attach an `onClick` function:

```
<button onClick={handleTableClick}>
    <tbody class='movie-list' id="mL">
        ....
    </tbody>
</button>
```

Then define `handleTableClick` function to handle click events.

```
function handleTableClick(event) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback. But sorry it's not working